# Append multiple NSMutableArray data to another NSMutableArray in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Let's say, there is `shipping` nsdictionary value is required to send to server, and there is `items` NSMutableArray inside `shipping` and, again there is `sub-items` NSMutableArray inside `items`.

That's why I've coded like that:

```
    for cake in cakes {
        for item in cakeItemsOpt {
            let optionalItem = [
                "item_req_mod_p_id": item.cakeItemModId,
                "l_req_mod_p_id": item.cakeModId,
                "mod_id": item.cakeModId,
                "mod_qty": item.cakeQty
            ]
            itemsOptional.add(optionalItem)
        }

        for item in cakeItemsReq {
            let requiredItem = [
                "item_req_mod_p_id": item.cakeItemModId,
                "l_req_mod_p_id": item.cakeModId,
                "mod_id": item.cakeModId,
                "mod_qty": "1"
            ]
            itemsRequired.add(requiredItem)
        }

        let cakeParam: NSDictionary = [
            "id": cake.cakeId,
            "qty": cake.cakeQty,
            "type": cake.cakeType,
            "name": cake.cakeName,
            "image": cake.cakeImage,
            "req_modifiers": itemsRequired,
            "opt_modifiers": itemsOptional
        ]
        items.add(cakeParam)
    }

    let param: NSDictionary = [
        "user_id": user_id,
        "token": token,
        "delivery": "del",
        "delivery_remark": delivery_remark,
        "delivery_date": delivery_date,
        "delivery_time": delivery_time,
        "delivery_charge": delivery_charge,
        "item": items,
        "payment_method_id": payment_id,
    ] as [String : Any]
```

`param` is main object to send to server.

But the result is not what I've expected,

```
["delivery_remark": "heavy", "payment_method_id": "4", "delivery": "del", "token": "0l8BwedwkZQltcFYFhCpicQZeQOhikyYLxa8R3u2", "item": <__NSArrayM 0x60800044ea90>(
{
    id = 11;
    image = "";
    name = "Red Velvet 16cm";
    "opt_modifiers" =     (
                {
            "item_req_mod_p_id" = 49;
            "l_req_mod_p_id" = 3;
            "mod_id" = 3;
            "mod_qty" = "";
        },
                {
            "item_req_mod_p_id" = 49;
            "l_req_mod_p_id" = 4;
            "mod_id" = 4;
            "mod_qty" = "";
        }
    );
    qty = 2;
    "req_modifiers" =     (
                {
            "item_req_mod_p_id" = 55;
            "l_req_mod_p_id" = 8;
            "mod_id" = 8;
            "mod_qty" = 1;
        },
                {
            "item_req_mod_p_id" = 56;
            "l_req_mod_p_id" = 3;
            "mod_id" = 3;
            "mod_qty" = 1;
        }
    );
    "run_no" = "6260-1c86";
    "small_candles" = "";
    "sponge_color_id" = "";
    "theme_id" = "";
    "theme_name" = "";
    type = item;
    "word_color_id" = "";
}
)
, "delivery_charge": "15.00", "user_id": "21", "delivery_time": "3", "delivery_date": "2017-02-27"]
```

There is `<__NSArrayM 0x60800044ea90>` included in my object. Please let me know how to correct my coding to get correct result. Thanks.

Comment: As always, do not use `NS(Mutable)Array/Dictionary` in Swift at all. You are fighting the strong type system. Use always native Swift `Array / Dictionary.`

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @NiravD  why `<__NSArrayM 0x60800044ea90>` is there?

Comment: @vadian what should I use then, please?

Comment: Was to be posted to a deleted answer. The proposed array concatenation was an odd loop. Assuming you're not concerned about unique instances  putting a2 into a3 and then a3 into a2..... (a3) [a,b,c] + (a2) [c,e,f] = (a2)[a,b,c,d,e,f]  + (a3)[a,b,c] = (a3)[a,b,c,e,f,g,a,b,c]. Could be achieved with loops. Honestly you should explore the Swift data types maybe nesting dictionary or arrays. or using JSON instead. NS data types still contain ObjC roots and are (for lack of better term) unswifty

Comment: @ppshein just use Array and Dictionary without the NS. To add if you want a mutable array using the Array type in swift it will have to be declared as a var. Non mutable is declared as a constant with let. Same is true of Dictionary in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Then i guess you want something like

```
    let data: [String : [String : [String : [String]]]]
    data = [
        "shipping" : ["items" : ["subitemKey" : ["subitemArray"]]]
    ]
```

So you have a dictionary that contains a dictionary for a key "shipping" that contains a dictionary for key "items" that contains arrays for keys of different subitems